# Excel looping through folder for workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a code that goes to a specific worksheet with filename and copy data to another worksheet called DataSummary the code is

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim MyFileName As String, MyPath As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
MyPath = "C:\testfiles\"
MyFileName = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls*")
Do Until MyFileName = ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyPath & MyFileName

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

        If ws.Name Like "*Ont*" Then
            ws.Activate
            LastRow1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row - 1 +     ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            strAddress2 = "T2:T" & LastRow1
            wbName = ThisWorkbook.Name
            Range(strAddress2).Value = Left(wbName, InStrRev(wbName, ".") - 1)

        End If
    Next
 wbName = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1)
 LastRow = Sheets(wbName).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 Sheets.Add Type:=xlWorksheet
 ActiveSheet.Name = "DataSummary2"
 For i = 2 To LastRow
 If Sheets(wbName).Cells(i, "A").Value = "ON" Then
 Sheets(wbName).Cells(i, "E").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("DataSummary2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
 End If
 Next i


    MyFileName = Dir
    ActiveWorkbook.Close True
Loop

End Sub
```

now this code works fine when used in same worksheet I have around 100 work books I want to edit this code so that it goes through all the work books and do the requited editing.

also next step after this is to combine all DataSummary worksheets into one single workbook

Comment: I had edited this code and also assigned path to the excel files, that code opens excel sheet but then gives error

Comment: ok I updated the code. with loop that can opens file in a folder

Comment: error is Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: first this code should go to folder, open each file and go to worksheet with name starting from  Ont, then copy the name of worksheet to the same worksheet at column T , then creates a new worksheet called DataSummary in the same workbook and copy all data from the old worksheet where column A has value ON...... I changed thisworkbook to Activeworkbook but it still does not work

Comment: Ok thanks , I believe error occurs while it enters the first loop

Comment: What he is asking is, when you run it and it stops because of an error, there will be a line in the code that is highlighted.  This is the line for which @fndwindow is asking.

Comment: I did some debugging and Error occurs at line       LastRow = Sheets(wbName).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: What is the value of wbName when is stops?

Comment: wbname is the name of worksheet where data was added in column T the worksheet name starts with Ont

Comment: I added mgbox it gives wbname value as Ontario19567

Comment: does that sheet exist in the activeworkbook?

Comment: So you have a sheet named the same as the workbook it is in? So the workbook is named Ontario19567 and there is a sheet in that workbook named Ontario19567 or is this sheet in a different workbook?

Comment: yes workbook name is Ontario19567.xls that's why I used     wbName = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1). when I run this code in a single workbook removing the loop when it enters a folder to find multiple workbooks. it works fine

Comment: ok to make it simple I changed it to wbName = ActiveSheet.Name but still no luck

Comment: Left an answer to what I think you want. It was kinda hard ;_; I am leaving soon but will try to help you more tomorrow. Please delete unnecessary comments above to reduce clutter.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

> first this code should go to folder, open each file and go to
>   worksheet with name starting from Ont, then copy the name of worksheet
>   to the same worksheet at column T , then creates a new worksheet
>   called DataSummary in the same workbook and copy all data from the old
>   worksheet where column A has value ON

In your code, I am really confused on what this is doing XD

```
wbName = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1)
```

I think you want to store the worksheet name to the variable `wbName` but that's a terrible name for a variable XD Also, it was rather confusing deciphering which book and which sheet you want from your code but I made my best attempt below.

I can't easily replicate your folder and files so this is **untested**. Make backups.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim MyFileName As String, MyPath As String
Dim newBook As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Application.DisplayAlerts = False

MyPath = "C:\testfiles\"
MyFileName = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls*")

Do Until MyFileName = ""

    Set newBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyPath & MyFileName)

    'add new sheet called DataSummary2
    newBook.Sheets.Add Type:=xlWorksheet
    ActiveSheet.name = "DataSummary2"

    For Each ws In newBook.Sheets

            If ws.name Like "*Ont*" Then

                lastRow1 = ws.UsedRange.Row - 1 + ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count 'not sure what the second half is doing XD
                strAddress2 = "T2:T" & lastRow1
                Range(strAddress2).Value = ws.name 'copy name of worksheet to column T

                lastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                'now copying to data summary
                For i = 2 To lastRow
                    If ws.Cells(i, "A").Value = "ON" Then
                    ws.Cells(i, "E").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("DataSummary2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                    End If
                Next i

            End If
    Next

    newBook.Close True
    MyFileName = Dir

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your effort, there are two workbooks , first workbook is having a macro and another workbook which is in C:\testfiles\ folder is having data.  the variable wbName is for the workbook that is having data, this workbook has many worksheets I only want worksheet that is starting from Ont. the variable wbName is storing the name of workbook and printing it to column T upto the last row there data exist in that worksheet. the trouble with my code is it is printing workbook name in the macro worksheet instead of data worksheet, that's why I believe there is an error in the first loop .

Comment: Bad day so far. Will try to look at it later but may not be till next week :/

Comment: Don't worry mate, thank you for your time and help. I will probably change the entire code and try to do it  another way since my goal is to merge the file. after this